# How to install the aarch64 toolchain for armv8 cortex-a53 on Debian?

Tags: gcc, arm, toolchain

I'm wanting to start low level programming on ARM chips. I've installed qemu and followed a few example programs for hello world type stuff, but now I want to target the latest Raspberry Pi, which has the ARMv8 `cortex-a53` and `neon-fp-armv8` FPU. I'm currently running Debian:

```
$ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: BunsenLabs
    Description:    BunsenLabs GNU/Linux 8.5 (Hydrogen)
    Release:    8.5
    Codename:   bunsen-hydrogen

$ cat /etc/debian_version
    8.5
```

I've currently installed the following toolchain:

```
binutils-arm-none-eabi
gcc-arm-none-eabi
gdb-arm-none-eabi
```

However, when I try to compile with `-mcpu=cortex-a53`, I receive the following error:

`arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option '-mcpu=cortex-a53'`

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
    arm-none-eabi-gcc (4.8.4-1+11-1) 4.8.4 20141219 (release)
```

I assumed I had an older GCC that did not contain that target CPU, so I tried to download the source for binutils, gcc, and gdb but I am unable to build binutils. It always fails when trying to `make all`.

binutils configuration:

```
$../../src/binutils-2.26.51/configure \
 --target=arm-none-eabi \
 --disable-nls
```

Build error:

```
$make -j4
    checking for bison... /home/nathan/development/tools/arm/src/binutils-2.26.51/missing bison -y
    checking for flex... /home/nathan/development/tools/arm/src/binutils-2.26.51/missing flex
    checking lex output file root... configure: error: cannot find output from /home/nathan/development/tools/arm/src/binutils-2.26.51/missing flex; giving up
    Makefile:3545: recipe for target 'configure-binutils' failed
    make[1]: *** [configure-binutils] Error 1
    no
    checking for bison... /home/nathan/development/tools/arm/src/binutils-2.26.51/missing bison -y
    checking for flex... /home/nathan/development/tools/arm/src/binutils-2.26.51/missing flex
    checking lex output file root... configure: error: cannot find output from /home/nathan/development/tools/arm/src/binutils-2.26.51/missing flex; giving up
    Makefile:4834: recipe for target 'configure-gas' failed
    make[1]: *** [configure-gas] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nathan/development/tools/arm/build/binutils-2.26.51'
    Makefile:844: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What are the proper steps I need to take in order to get a toolchain setup to compile for an aarch64 `cortex-a53` architecture?

**Edit 1**

Discovered through the comments, I need to install the aarch64 toolchain, not the arm toolchain. Still clueless.

Comment: 32-bit ARM compilers don't support cortex-a53 optimizations (AFAIK). The current build of Raspian is running as ARMHF (ARMv6 with hardware floating point). It does not support ARMv8 64-bit code. armhf code will run just fine on the cortex-a53 CPU (in 32-bit mode), but if you want to run 64-bit ARMv8 code in Linux, you'll need to get a Linaro-supported ARM64 system (e.g. Dragonboard410c)  or wait for Raspbian to be updated with support for 64-bit ARM.

Comment: You're on the right track (the 32-bit backend didn't know about Cortex-A53 until GCC 4.9), but TBH it's unlikely to matter a great deal - the compiler-visible differences between v7 and v8 AArch32 more or less amount to a few extra NEON instructions and the crypto/CRC extensions, and optimising for Cortex-A7 should be close enough. Personally I just grab the Linaro toolchain [binary releases](http://www.linaro.org/downloads/), but if you want to get your build working please detail the actual error.

Comment: @BitBank I'm trying to program to the CPU directly, without an OS involved.

Comment: @Notlikethat Even though going from v7 v8 won't really make a difference, I still would like to know how to setup a proper toolchain. I've added the error I get from make to the question. Also, you seem to mention aarch32, but I'm wanting aarch64, am I building the wrong things here?

Comment: @nathan Well in that case you'll want an AArch64-targeted GCC anyway (which do start at 4.8); due to the significantly different instruction set and the ~25 years worth of cruft and hacks holding the 32-bit backend together, AArch64 was implemented as a new separate target. As for building, it looks like you might be missing some tools - does `apt-get build-dep binutils-arm-none-eabi` (or other relevant package) pull in anything new?

Comment: @Notlikethat `build-dep` was not able to be found. `binutils-arm-none-eabi` was the package I had installed, along with the rest of the `arm-none-eabi` tool chain that produced the `unable to locate option -mcpu=cortex-a53` error, because the version of gcc was behind.

Comment: Not found? That's odd, [it should be a standard command AFAIK](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-sourcehandling.en.html#s-build-dep) - anyway, it's only a cheeky trick for when you're building something that _some_ packaged version of exists, to save having to manually work out what you need - which in this case would appear to be at least `flex`. Building any GNU tool always seems to require just about every _other_ GNU tool...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Ubuntu 18.04 you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a53 hello_world.c
```

The package `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` is at version `4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2`

However, for Raspberry Pi, you should just download the official binaries from https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools which is the more reliable way to do it as explained at: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64273/installing-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/83215#83215

Finally, for bare metal, I was not able to find the analogue of `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, I wonder why: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/issues/68

Comment: @TheExcitedEngineer thanks, it's due to Stack Exchange's idiotic post deletion algorithms regardless of how many million rep asker has, reposted at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/issues/68

Answer (score 2):

## You can try my Latest Pre-Built Open-Sourced GCC Toolchains for Raspberry Pi from this [Github Project](https://github.com/abhiTronix/raspberry-pi-cross-compilers):

**This Project Summary:** This project contains the UpToDate set of Precompiled/Pre-Built Raspberry pi GCC Cross & Native Compilers Binaries, saving your tons of time(No compiling or Error Handling needed whatsoever). Just Extract, Link & Enjoy complete GCC(Raspberry Pi) functionality in your Machine. You can use its native compilers for Raspberry Pi(Can be used along with old & slow 6.3.0 GCC), Or use the Cross-Compiler in any Linux Machine(Tested on Latest Ubuntu/bionic x64) to compile programs for your Raspberry Pi. All these compilers binaries are Raspberry Pi hardware optimized for enhanced overall performance.

**The Supported GCC Versions are:**

- GCC 6.3.0
- GCC 7.4.0
- GCC 8.2.0
- GCC 8.3.0

**Supported Environments:**

- **Cross-Compiler:** All Linux Distros (x32/x64) are currently supported.
- **Native-Compiler:** All Raspberry Pi version/model with Raspbian OS is supported. Other OS may/may-not work.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: can you produce gcc 7.3.0 ?

Comment: Maybe not, since it is now obsoleted and replaced by newer binaries. You can rather use my GCC 7.4.0 toolchains.

Comment: okay, that's really a pity.. unfortunately the app cannot be compile using gcc740 (tried it) and i dont have knowledge to fix that. it will absolutely do wonder if you can release for 730 even though it is obsolete..